# Django DB backup and restore

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-orm, django-migrations

I am using Postgres in my Django project. My concern is regarding database backup and restore.
Let's say I have a Django model named TestModel with name as a char field in that TestModel. I have ran Django's migrations and have inserted the data into model from Frontend. Then I take backup of database using django's dumpdata command and store it into backup.json.

At some point after backup, I had to delete my database, change the field name 'name' to 'machine_name' of TestModel and then I ran migrations. Now when I try to insert data by loaddata command using my earlier backup file named backup.json, it gives me error for that name field that I had changed.

I tried:

1. Django's built-in commands like dumpdata and loaddata.
2. Third-party library django-dbbackup

I need to know how this database backup and restore is carried out in production when there are changes in database schema. How can I know the changes in database schema from one backup to another and if there are changes in schema I still be able to restore my old data into new database.

Comment: This is a generic issue, if you change the schema under the data you are responsible for matching them up again. Your best bet is to make the schema changes then dump the data. The other option is to write code that takes in the old data dump and changes it to match the new schema. To that end you should take a look at [Data Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver I want to know how this is handled in production when application is deployed at client-side.

Comment: I don't use Django's migration system so I can't help you with that. I use [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) and for that I create a script that does the data migration.